# which version of Visual C++ runtime libraries is necessary?

Tags: c++

Does the latest vcredist from microsoft (version 2010) include the previous versions (2008 SP1 and 2005 SP1) or do I need to install all 3 of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need all of them.

Answer (score 2):

It only includes the latest. If you're using a binary built against an older version, you will need to supply the exact version of that version of the runtime if you want to use that binary.

Every project built with MSVS2010 is built against version 10 of the runtime (I'm not sure if you can change that, but I think not).