# Which version of visual C++ runtime libraries

Tags: c++

does the 2010 vcredist package from microsoft contain the 2008 SP1 version and the 2005 SP1 version?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540800/which-version-of-visual-c-runtime-libraries-is-necessary

Answer (score 1):

No, it only contains the VS2010 stuff, if you are using for example a third party library that was created with VS2008 you will have to include the VS2008 vcredist as well